# Как заставить работать созданные DOM элементы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

К примеру было

```
<div id="tatata">
<a href="http://hello.ru" id="hello">hello</a>    
<a href="http://goodbye.com/">good bye</a>    
</div>
<script>
    $('#tatata a').click(function () {
        $('#tatata').html('<a href="http://ya.ru/">yandex</a><a href="http://google.ru/">google</a>');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

В данном примере уже по клику google или yandex скрипт не работает, пропускает клик. Как заставить перехватывать?

Извиняюсь, если что-то не так написал, какие-то формулировки и т.п. 
p.s. новичок :(

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. Налажал в своём варианте. Господин @Чад прав.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте делегирование!

```
$('body').on('click', '#tatata a', function(){})
```

Comment: Тока body в кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Клик не пропускается, просто вы обновлением дива tatata стираете элементы a к которым был привязан клик. И у Вас в этом диве появляются новые элементы "a" уже без привязанного события click.

Не понятен смысл такой задачи в рамках вашего кода, но сделать можно так:

```
...
function eventClick(){$('#tatata').html(...); $('#tatata a').click(eventClick);}
...
$('#tatata a').click(eventClick);
...
```

Comment: А как их заново привязать к событию click?

Comment: Смысл в том, что ссылки подгружаются использую ajax запрос, т.к. код довольно длинный, дабы не запутать опустил его.

Comment: Что-то у меня не получается, вот код (посмотри пожалуйста):
<script>
$(".num a").click(function(){
 var num = $(this).text();
 page(num);
 return false;
 });
 
function pages(page){
var send = $.getJSON('/num.php', {n: page}, function(obj){
$('.num').html(obj.nav);
});}
</script>
ссылки вида
<Div class="num">
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
</div>

Comment: Таки где привязка клика после обновления контейнера ссылками?

Comment: Так нет тут, вот и написал тебе!

Comment: Таки дядя, а я что должен за тебя код писать? Всю информацию я предоставил, на вопрос ответил.